# Bokeh: pass vars to CustomJS for Widgets

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

A nice thing about Bokeh is that callbacks can be specified from the Python layer that result actions on the javascript level without the need of bokeh-server.  So one can create interactive widgets that run in a  browser without an Ipython or Bokeh server running.

The 0.9.3. documentation gives an example that I can reproduce in an ipython notebook:
http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#cutomjs-for-widgets

```
from bokeh.io import vform
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("callback.html")
x = [x*0.005 for x in range(0, 200)]
y = x

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
        var data = source.get('data');
        var f = cb_obj.get('value')
        x = data['x']
        y = data['y']
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            y[i] = Math.pow(x[i], f)
        }
        source.trigger('change');
    """)

slider = Slider(start=0.1, end=4, value=1, step=.1, title="power", callback=callback)

layout = vform(slider, plot)
show(layout)
```

I want to adapt code like this to create some simple online assignments.  My question is how can I pass other variables from python to javascript directly without invoking a Slider.  For example suppose I want the Javascript to become:

```
y[i] = Math.pow(x[i], A*f)
```

where the A was defined in an ipython code cell above (for example A = 10).  It's easy enough to define 'var A = 10' in the javascript but I'd like to set the value of A and other variables in python and then pass them into this javascript.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Bokeh 0.9.3 you can only pass "Bokeh Models" (e.g. things like data sources and renderers), not arbitrary python objects. But we are working on extending bokeh documents with a simple namespace concept that can be mirrored easily.

Comment: Thanks, that would be amazing.  I've created a few basic interactive visualizations with Bokeh server and interact from the ipywidgets library in Ipython (note [Bokeh documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/notebook.html#id5) refers to the now deprecated Ipython.html.widgets library so should be changed to ipywidgets). But if one could solve the above problem it would become easy to generate and modify interactive content for people without python/Bokeh installed.  That could *revolutionize* teaching in lots of disciplines.