# Pass variables from bokeh to JS via CustomJS

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

In the bokeh example http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-hover
the dictonary "`links`" is passed to the JS by adding it at the end of the code block with: 
....

```
""" % links
```

Is it possible to pass over two variables and what would the syntax look like?
I tried different versions like

```
""" % links,myvar
""" % ('links','myvar')
""" % links, % myvar
```

but they all create errors or do not work.
I also found this 
[Bokeh: pass vars to CustomJS for Widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32318890/bokeh-pass-vars-to-customjs-for-widgets)
but perhaps there is an update?
Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into general python string formatting (there isn't anything Bokeh-specific within that example).

But some options would be

```
JS_CODE = """
var variable_1 = %s
var variable_2 = %s
""" % (var1, var2)
```

or

```
JS_CODE = """
var variable_1 = {0}
var variable_2 = {1}
""".format(var1, var2)
```

or to set as a list

```
JS_CODE = """
var list_variable = %s
""".format(str(list_var))
```

docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatexamples